# Why are the values different? C++ pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I was googling a solution to find out the length of an array in C++. One of the solutions I found is this

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
int size = *(&arr+1)-arr; //size is the length of the array
```

I was confused between `&arr` and `arr` since both give the base address of the array. Googled again and found that `&arr + 1` gives the address of next block of memory that is not part of the array where `arr + 1` gives the address of next element in the array.

I have written the following code to test out the difference between `&arr` and `arr`:

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
printf("value of &arr + 1 - &arr = %d\n", &arr + 1 - &arr);
printf("value of *(&arr + 1) - arr = %d\n", *(&arr + 1) - arr);
```

The answer to the first `printf` is `1` where as the second `printf` gives `6`. This is the part that confuses me: Since both `&arr` and `arr` hold the base address of the same array, why are the results different?

Comment: Try https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent

Comment: &arr + 1 - &arr = &arr - &arr + 1 = 1.

Comment: @solarflare -- not so, `*(&arr + 1) - arr == 6`. Why? `&arr` is a *pointer to array of char [6]*, thus `&arr + 1` is a *pointer (to the address immediately after) array of char [6]*. When you dereference the *pointer to array*, you get an *array* which by virtue of conversion to a pointer on access is the address to the `int` (in this case) immediately after `arr`. So `*(&arr + 1) - arr` will give the ***number of elements*** in the array of `int`, just as `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` would.

Comment: Note: more useful here might have been to print out the addresses of the objects you were working (non-object in the case of `&arr +1`) with to see where they were laid out in memory  that would be the `%p` format option in `printf`.

Comment: You forget about the type system. `+1` on a pointer means to point to the next thing of what the pointer is pointing to.  It doesn't mean +1 byte .

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin he's not dereferencing it in the first line, he's basically doing pointer arithmetic which gives the result 1.  I showed why.

Comment: Okay, I was referring to the first `int size = *(&arr+1)-arr;`, sorry for the confusion. You could always do `int size = (char*)*(&arr+1)-(char*)arr;` to get the number of ***bytes*** in the array.

Answer (score 7):

> Since both "&arr" and "arr" hold the base address of the same array, why are the results different?

Because the **type** is different. Pointer arithmetic is affected by the type of the pointer, and more specifically, the type of the pointed object.

`&arr` is a pointer to an array of 6 int. Adding 1 to that increments to the next array of 6 ints (if it was an element of an array of arrays).

`arr`, although is an array, decays to pointer to the first element of the array when its value is used, such as in the pointer arithmetic expression. The decayed value is a pointer to an int and adding 1 to that moves the pointer to the next integer.

P.S. You can use `std::size` instead. Or `std::extent` pre-C++17. Or `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` pre-C++11.

`*(&arr + 1) - arr` probably works, but technically indirects through a past-the-end pointer (to an object which does not exist), which is typically undefined behaviour. I'm not sure whether there might be some exception to the rule considering the value is only used to decay to a pointer.

Comment: Better yet, you can use `std::array` or `std::vector`

Comment: What's got me wondering is just how legal is all this.Pointer arithmetic is only valid within the object. Is there a special exemption for one-past the object tricks? Ha! There you go. Should have clicked to see the edit sooner! I can't find an exception either.

Comment: @user4581301 The pointer arithmetic is legal. It is well defined to add one to pointer to an object as if it was an array of length one, and the result can be used as if it was a pointer past the end of the hypothetical array. The indirection is dubious, but *maybe* OK. Last I read, the legalese around the matter is fuzzy, but it is my understanding that the intention is for it to be legal.

Comment: @user4581301 regarding the pointer arithmetic: While the +1 is OK, it may actually be indeed technically UB to perform the subtracting pointer arithmetic, since those are not within the same array. But this is probably in the class of UB that no sane compiler would break because it would prevent for example implementation of `std::vector` in standard C++.

Comment: That's the example I was going to use. Computing the length of a full `std::vector`. The demonstrates intent even if they have the formal wording a little wiggly.

Comment: @user4581301 I was thinking any pointer arithmetic within a vector, since there can't be an "array of T" there. There's just individual T objects that re-use storage of a `char` array (or similar). This makes the "pointer arithmetic is valid only within an array" problematic.

Comment: I thought they may have had some wiggle room in using *object*, rather than *array*, but no. C++17 uses *array object*  consistently though **expr.add**.

Answer (score 0):

&arr and arr are different pointers.
arr is the address of first element of array "arr".
But &arr is the address of pointer arr. There is address of array "arr" in &arr address.
So it's address of address of array.
Thus, &arr is unexpectable, and *(&arr + 1) is also unexpectable.
Because we don't know which value is saved in next address of &arr.

Let me explain of your two printf statements.
&arr + 1 - &arr always returns 1. Because it adds one to &arr and subtracts &arr again, so the result is 1.
*(&arr + 1) - arr returns unexpectable result. Because *(&arr + 1) is unexpectable and arr is also unexpectable, so the result is unexpectable.

That's why those two results are different.

Sorry for not user-friendly answer.
Thanks, Best regards.

Jin Yi.

Comment: *"Because we don't know which value is saved in next address of &arr."* -- we don't have to know what is saved there. As used above, all you care about is the *address*, not the *content* at that address.